# WordPress 500 Error On Specific Server

Tags: linux, wordpress, permissions, server

I am managing a 3 linux server system: an NFS server and two web servers. There is this new WordPress website that I installed, which works on one of the web servers, but not the other (I know this because I disabled access to that server and the site worked perfectly).

When the bad server is enabled and used, I receive 500 errors. The two servers have the same files, permissions etc., all of which were configured on the NFS server. The configuration files on each web server are also the same.

The error logged is `End of script output before headers: index.php`

Any ideas on what is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can set php display errors like below to see what happens:

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

When I meet your case, I see that we need add a space after

```
/root/index.php
/wp-content/index.php
/themes/<theme>/index.php
```

or some syntax errors happened.

Comment: where does that first bit of code go?

What do you mean by the second part of your answer?